# angularjs2 test Observable in karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, observable

according to the http client tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) I've created a simple webservice. The service works in the browser:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {Response} from "angular2/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class XMLService {
    constructor(private _http:Http) {

    }

    private _xmlUrl:string = 'resources/mocks/example_xml_string/minimal.xml';

    public getXML() {
        console.log("service called");
        return this._http.get(this._xmlUrl)
            .map(this.mapXML)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private mapXML(response:Response){
        console.log("mapping called");
        return <string> response.text();
    }

    private handleError(error:Response) {
        console.log("error called");
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

I wrote also a test, according using the ng-test-seed infrastructure (which works mostly as expected):

```
import { it, xit, iit, describe, expect, inject, injectAsync, beforeEachProviders, fakeAsync, tick } from 'angular2/testing';
import {XMLService} from "../../../../../app/de/q21/europass/service/xml.service";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {Response} from "angular2/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';



describe('xml service', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(() => [XMLService, Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);

    it('should get an europass xml string', inject([XMLService], fakeAsync((xmlService) => {

        var xmlResult="";
        var xmlError = "";
        xmlService.getXML()
            .subscribe(
                result =>
                    xmlResult = result
                ,
                error => {
                    xmlError = <any>error;
                    console.log("Error: " + error)
                }
            );

        console.log("result: "+ xmlResult);


    })));
});
```

The test is working, the service starts to fetch the .xml via xhr, but the result is empty. Possibly the tests ends before the file is transfered?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Tom

Comment: closed, this was a bug in this version and it works with > = beta.16
(must be used without calling fakeSync())